# How to get context of the implemented callback inside a method of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I've defined the next header for a Fragment:

```
public class AllVideosFragment extends Fragment implements AutomaticCallback{
```

Inside of this Fragment, I have the next function to handle a spinner:

```
// Listener called when spinner item selected
        spinnerLanguages.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Get selected row data to show on screen
                String language = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSpinnerRow)).getText().toString();

                if(language.equals(getString(R.string.str_en)))
                    Hawk.put(Config.TV_LANGUAGE, "en");
                if(language.equals(getString(R.string.str_es)))
                    Hawk.put(Config.TV_LANGUAGE, "es");

                //We need to retrive data again
                new AutomaticRequest().getLives(String.valueOf(Hawk.get(Config.TV_LANGUAGE)), **CONTEXT OF THE CALLBACK**);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });
```

If I would have the method outside of the spinner handle method, I could use "this", but inside I don't know what I need to use.

```
new AutomaticRequest().getLives(String.valueOf(Hawk.get(Config.TV_LANGUAGE)), this);
```

Which method I need to call in replacement of "this"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: getactivity() use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in an anonymous scope and `this` will refer to the scope. If you want to pass an outer `this` you have to explicitly name it in this case

```
AllVideosFragment.this
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the current callback's context, `FragmentName.this` will refer to fragment context while `getActivity()` refers to the activity context on which your fragment is being hosted. For your ease simple make a `Context context` in global scope, initialise it in fragments' `onViewCreated()` method like, `context = getActivity()` and use it anywhere in your fragment.

Comment: Would you please elaborate how can I improve this answer? Or what was hidden in question?

Comment: Also please read once, when to give a negative rating to any answer. But thanks :)

Comment: sorry, i was blind :) ... next time mark the code ... :) also things about context are unncesery

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will make it sure next time. :)

Answer (score -1):

the answer is:

```
new AutomaticRequest().getLives(String.valueOf(Hawk.get(Config.TV_LANGUAGE)), getActivity().this);
```

Answer (score -2):

AllVideosFragment.this.getActivity();